# Question about indirect object?

Tags: indirect-objects

> Grammar is driving me crazy.

What would *crazy* be in this sentence? Is it an indirect object?

Comment: So what's the question?

Comment: Before you wish to get an answer, you have to put effort into asking the question. Unless, you don't think the time of the people who can answer your question is worth the time or effort you need to put in to figuring out what it is that you wish to ask.

Comment: It's an adjective (a predicate adjective in function).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, not an indirect object (nor a modifier), but an **objective predicative complement**. **Me** is the direct object of the verb *driving*, and the adjective *crazy* is describing a property that is ascribed of *me*.

Comment: Ok that makes sense

Comment: Further, it's a resultative (showing ensuing state) rather than a depictive. 'They shot him dead' vs 'The ants were eating him alive'.